# How to build OPA bundles when data files can exceed 1gb size?

Tags: open-policy-agent

I'm trying to build an OPA bundle. Some of the included raw `data.json` files are larger than 1GB (1073741824 bytes) and exceed the preconfigured `size_limit_bytes`. Build CLI command:

```bash
./opa build -b /path/to/bundle
```

causes the error:

```
error: load error: bundle /path/to/bundle: bundle file extra/data.json size (1073741825 bytes) exceeds configured size_limit_bytes (1073741824 bytes)
```

OPA version: 0.62.1

Is there a way to specify custom `size_limit_bytes` for `opa build`? For `opa run` it is possible to configure this parameter via the config file or `--set`, but there is no such option for `opa build`.

As a workaround - it is possible to build .tar.gz directly using tar and gzip, but using `opa build` is a preferred way. Any options to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid the bundle size limit is [not exposed as a CLI parameter to `opa build`.](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/cli/#opa-build) It thus falls back to the [default of 1G](https://github.com/open-policy-agent/opa/blob/1a1ff2bb5349597b8fa69575cddc8290b38c2b4a/bundle/bundle.go#L43).

You could

- build your own `opa` binary with the default changed
- use tar + gzip as you described
- [download an `eopa` binary](https://docs.styra.com/enterprise-opa/how-to/install/local) -- its `eopa build` command has a much higher default

(Note that I just brought Enterprise OPA up to give you an easy way out. The higher default is not part of its value proposition. And you don't need a license to run it for your purposes, you should be able to go from `opa build ...` straight to `eopa build ...`)

Comment: Ok, thank you! Likely `eopa` can manage larger files. Both `build` and `run` consume lots of RAM though, but it is expected...  
`tar`+`gzip` is also a fallback option along with building a custom `opa` binary.